# How to use pip for Python3.10 instead of Python 3.9?

Tags: python, pip

I would like to use the Python toolkit Neurokit2 (https://neurokit2.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html) on Mac OS 12.3.1 in Python 3.10.4.

Python 3.10.4 was installed via homebrew. Python 3.9 was also installed via homebrew because of dependencies for jupyterlab and scipy.

When installing Neurokit2 via `pip3 install neurokit2` pip automatically installs the toolkit only for python 3.9. The installation is located in `harddrive\opt\homebrew\lib\python3.9\site-packages\` with the foldernames `neurokit2` and `neurokit2-0.1.7.dist-info`.

Simply copying both folders to the respective python3.10 path (`harddrive\opt\homebrew\lib\python3.10\site-packages\`) does not do the job.

Furthermore, the command `pip3.10 install neurokit2` also installs the toolkit into the python3.9 path.

Do I have to uninstall and then reinstall pip so that it automatically gets assigned with Python3.10, or are there better ways to solve this problem?

Comment: You probably should have created a virtual environment for py3.10 rather than installing another version of python on your machine via homebrew.

Comment: This is a class of problems that using Nix instead of Homebrew would entirely avoid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to handle multiple versions of Python in a single machine is to use pyenv.

You can install multiple versions and choose which one to activate at a local path or at a global context :
https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv

Comment: I'd argue that [Nix](https://nixos.org/) does it even better than pyenv does -- for one, it's not specific to Python (and can be used to manage arbitrary software written in arbitrary languages); but when you _are_ using it for Python, it covers not just interpreters but libraries as well.

Comment: Sure Nix seems more complete, but i find pyenv more straightforward when you just need different versions of Python. Habits die hard i guess

Answer (score 2):

You can try: python3.10 -m pip

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

If you really want to make sure you are using a specific version of Python pip, you can use the full path to the Python executable as your first command then `-m pip` before your pip command. For example:

```
C:/Users/yourpath/Python310/python.exe -m pip your_pip_command
```